# creating a pipe from a parent process stdin to a childprocess stdin

Tags: c++, c, linux, pipe

I try to transfer the stdin of my parent process to a child process.

stdin -->  parentprocess --> child_eingabe[1] --> child_eingabe[0] --> childprocess --> stdin

My small program works in that way, that i can write stuff from my parent process into the pipe (with the write() command), and it reaches my child via stdin. What not works, is that the stdin of the parent is directly written INTO the pipe. Does this work as I plan?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        // string to the client
        string sClient = "/tmp/myecho";

        int child_eingabe[2];

        cout << "Creating pipes " << endl;

        if(pipe(child_eingabe) < 0) {
                cout << " Error in pipe " << endl;
        } 

        // forking now
        pid_t pid;

        cout << "Forking process" << endl;

        if((pid = fork()) == 0) {


                close(child_eingabe[1]);

                int fid = -1;
                if(fid=dup2(child_eingabe[0], 0) < 0)
                        cout << "Could not redirect STDIN" << endl;

                close(child_eingabe[0]);

                int result = execve(sClient.c_str(),0,0);
                cout << "something went wrong while starting client" << endl;

                if (result != 0) {
                        cout << "Could not start" << endl;
                }
                exit(0);
        }
        close(child_eingabe[0]);

//      if(dup2(0,child_eingabe[1]) < 0)
        if(dup2(child_eingabe[1],0) < 0)
                cout << "Could not redirect STDIN" << endl;

        close(0);
        while(1)
        {
                sleep(1);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

If I see everything correctly, the second dup2 in the parent part does not what i expected it to do.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you redirect the parents stdin to the pipe? As I understand you, that's exactly what you want to avoid. Removing the second dup2 and close(0) should leave your parent with a stdin that is completely disconnected from the pipe.

EDIT: After clarification of the question - Want to duplicate data from parent stdin to child stdin.

Create the child pipe as you do, then *manually* read stdin in the parent and pass data to the child with `write()` on `child_eingabe[1]`

Comment: I try to redirect/copy the stdin of the PARENT to the stdin of the CHILD, using Pipes.

Comment: If you want to *keep* the existing stdin for the child, don't do any redirection at all.

Comment: I try to transfer the stdin of the parent INTO the child.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me, sorry. Do you want to "get data from parents stdin and manually pass it to child" or "let child take over parents stdin" or "let child share parents stdin"?

Comment: I don't understand the real difference between the second and the third option, but I would like to to "let child share parents stdin" Sorry for beeing so unclear, but I am using pipes for the first time, and perhaps I did not understand the basics of it.

Comment: Then you don't do any redirection at all. The child inherits the parents stdin, they'll have shared access to it.

Comment: D'oh! Really? Let me write an example for that, but thank you again for your help. Can both read from stdin, and get both the same text? I will test that. EDIT: I checked it, the problem is, that the parent and the child dont copy the stdin, in other words, one single line of input goes either to the stdin of the parent or the stdin of the child

Comment: OK, now I think I see what you're asking. You need to manually copy data read from parents stdin, so use what I said in the answer (don't do anything with parents stdin), and manually write() it to the parents end of the child pipe.

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually need the input to go to the parent process?

If not, you can close the parent's stdin, than all input goes to child process.

Otherwise, the easiest way should be what Erik wrote.

Other way (not shure if it applies to your case), should be redirecting the child's stdin and the parent's stdout to a pipe. Your parent reads the input and writes it to it's stdout (the child's input).